# Python asking for two arguments when one needs to be passed

Tags: python, object, inheritance

I'm new to python and was working on this code:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, shape):
        self.shape = shape

    def shapeName(self):
        print(self.shape)

class Rectangle(Shape):                         # Rectangle class inherits Shape

    count = 0                                   # static variable

    def __init__(self, name):
        Shape.__init__(self.name)
        print('In Rectangle')
        Rectangle.count = Rectangle.count + 1


rec1 = Rectangle('Rectangle')
rec2 = Rectangle('Rectangle')

rec1.shapeName()
rec2.shapeName()

print( Rectangle.count )
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Python32\python.exe C:/Users/ashutosh/PycharmProjects/Test/InheritanceTest.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/ashutosh/PycharmProjects/Test/InheritanceTest.py", line 17, in <module>

rec = Rectangle('Rectangle')

File "C:/Users/ashutosh/PycharmProjects/Test/InheritanceTest.py", line 13, in __init__

Shape.__init__(name)

TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The first argument to constructor is the current object and second is the name of the shape. Then why it is saying that I have to pass 2 arguments?

Comment: You need to add self before name

Comment: You should generally call parent class methods with `super`.

Comment: Please check the edit, no luck.  Also, I replaced Shape.__init__ with super.__init__ but still error persist

Comment: @Ashutosh that's because it should be `super().__init__(name)` (note parentheses)

Comment: This is another one of those questions that gets asked pretty much all the time.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense The one that gets asked all the time is where people forget to include the `self` parameter, or include it as an argument. This is very related of course :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Shape` is a class, not an object, so when you call `Shape.__init__` there's no self variable. In other words, there is no instance of Shape to call init on. The instance you want is the subclass instance of `Shape` that you have, i.e. `self` (the `Rectangle`). You could simply pass self, like this:

```
Shape.__init__(self, name)
```

or make use of the `super` keyword:

```
super(Rectangle, self).__init__(name)
```

The `super` keyword allows you to implicitly refer to your superclass, without using the name.

In Python 3.0 you can simply write `super().__init__(name)` without even the child reference.

Comment: @wim Yep, good link. Here's a (possibly) relevant excerpt: `Superclasses must use super if their subclasses do (sometimes)`

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass `self` explicitly to `Shape.__init__`.

So your rectangle class should look like this:

```
class Rectangle(Shape):                         # Rectangle class inherits Shape

    count = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        Shape.__init__(self, name)
        print('In Rectangle')
```